# Internet Speed Tests

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, speed, broadband

I've recently had fibre broadband (FTTP) installed (900mbps/100mbps). One thing I've noticed which doesn't seem to make much sense is the results of speed tests.

As above my connection is now 900mbps down and 100mpbs up. Over WiFi my devices are getting around 300-500mpbs down which seems about right from posts I've read online (also the provider only garuntees 450mpbs down).

I've tested the speeds using speedtest.net and fast.com

Both show similar results but if I set the speed test off and then switch tabs to a search or anything else when I go back to the speed test the result shows I have double the speed almost.

e.g. I ran the test on fast.com before coming here and got 330mpbs down, I set the test off again and switched tabs to come here and write this post. Now going back to the fast.com tab my result is 780mbps down.

I can't work out/understand why there's such a drastic difference. If anything I'd expect the speed to drop as I'm now using two tabs rather than one.

Does anyone know why I see the higher speed when the tab running the test isn't active?

Comment: A variance from 300Mbps to 700Mbps on WiFi is not unheard of as there dozens of possible factors. If you really want to test speeds, you MUST do it on a good, wired Ethernet connection and not over WiFi, especially at these speeds. Plus once you get above 250Mb/s or so, other factors come into play in speed tests, like system resource usage, Internet security software, and other things. I am engineer for a company that supplies FTTH internet in excess of 2.5Gb/s in some areas and speed testing is a real nightmare sometimes.

Comment: @acejavelin I'm not to worried by the speed varying. What confuses me is that its specific and repeatable. Every test I've run where the active tab is the speed test the result is 300-500mbps. Then if I run the test but open another tab and sit in that tab till the test is done the speed goes up to 700-800mbps.

Comment: I understand what you are saying and honestly can't explain that... Have you tried it with a different web browser, say a Chromium based one vs FireFox?